# Json missing model name in mvc db

Tags: angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc

Using entity framework I scaled a model 'beer.cs'

```
  public class Beer
  {
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public bool HasTasted {get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }
```

I took the automated code from BeersController and switched it to output Json

```
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
        return View(db.Beers.ToList());
   }

    public ActionResult IndexVM()
    {
        return Json(db.Beers.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Now the problem is, I'm getting json back without a model name so it looks like this

```
[{"ID":1,"HasTasted":true,"Name":"Root Beer Ale"},{"ID":2,"HasTasted":false,"Name":"Dragons Breath"},{"ID":3,"HasTasted":false,"Name":"ScAles"},{"ID":4,"HasTasted":true,"Name":"Dragons Breath"}]
```

Which I believe is the reason it's not rendering on my ng-repeat model.

```
 <p>{{model | json}}</p>
    <table class="table">
        <tr ng-repeat="beer in model.Beers">
```

Is there other ways to use ng-repeat or possibly change `db.Beers.ToList()` to something else that will give me a model name?

---

BeerCtrl.js

```
angular.module('AngularDemo.BeerController', [])
.controller('BeerCtrl', [
    '$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.model = {};

        $http.get('/Beers/IndexVM').success(function (data) {
            $scope.model = data;
    });
}]);
```

Comment: `return Json(new {Beers = db.Beers.ToList()}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` gives you a name for your json object.. but not sure if that's all you're missing

Comment: The collection of `Beer` objects *is* the model. I would think you'd just be able to write `ng-repeat="beer in model"`.

Comment: To make things easier - could you post the Angular code that takes in the JSON data from the controller please?

Comment: @JasonEvans I added the angular controller to the post

Comment: What happens if you change the code to be `<tr ng-repeat="beer in model">` Is the data displayed in that case?

Comment: `ng-repeat="beer in model"`  works! :D

Comment: @JamieD77 Awesome I have a model name now, this is important to know for organizing data later on, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`ng-repeat="beer in model"`

The property `Beers` does not exist - the data read from the controller is being set into the `model`, which acts as an array of objects. Thus you can iterate `model` itself when accessing the beer data.